# How to use different bootstrap classes with if countmodules in joomla 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, joomla

I have a question for joomla and bootstrap templates.

I have an issue with a template i build for joomla from scratch.
The customer that wanted to build this template gave me a certain demo from othet cms and want me to build the template for him, that's ok until now. The demo is here->http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/49165.html if you want to see it.

I need some help with the if countmodules statement to use different bootstrap class for the divs that i use in the main section (sidebar-l and component).

I want to use 3-column-class for sidebar-left-position and component to class of 9 if sidebar-module exists, else component to class of 12 if sidebar left position dont exist.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

1. Your theme 2 columns layout. We need see your index.php
2. Read to Joomla protostar template index.php

you will get the solution.

```
    // Adjusting content width
if ($this->countModules('position-7') && $this->countModules('position-8'))
{
    $span = "span6";
}

<main id="content" role="main" class="<?php echo $span;?>">
                <!-- Begin Content -->
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-3" style="xhtml" />
                <jdoc:include type="message" />
                <jdoc:include type="component" />
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-2" style="none" />
                <!-- End Content -->
            </main>
```

Comment: Protostar theme is using bootstrap2 right?
I built the template iwth bootstrap 3 so instead of span* i use col-*-*
The index.php is here
<!---<div id="mainbody" class="col-md-12">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
   <?php if ($this->countModules('sidebar-l')): ?>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
     <jdoc:include type="modules" name="sidebar-l" style="none" />
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="main-component">
                  <jdoc:include type="message" />
      <jdoc:include type="component" />
     </div>
    </div>
            </div>
  </div>
 </div>--->

Comment: Protostar theme is using bootstrap2 right? YES Correct.But you can develop your own way using bootstrap 3 classes